# multiple treeviews for data selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, treeview, html-lists

I have an assignment that needs to be done in a very specific way. I have all the back end code done, but cant seem to figure this part out, and it's driving me mad. Essentially the UI is required to have 2 tree views one on the right and one on the left. The left tree view will be populated with states, and each state will have multiple children. The right will be empty to start. There will be two buttons. Include, and exclude. when children from the left view are selected, and then include is clicked they will move to the right tree. If the user decides to move them back they need to move to the same place they were under the same parent. Last, but not least, there can only be one of each child so we can't have duplicates when moving the children to new parents.

I can use any combination of html, css, javascript, and jquery.

here is what i have so far. I have tried many other things, but this is just the most recent.

CSS

```
#menutree li {
       list-style: none;          /* all list item li dots invisible */
         }

       li .menu_label + input[type=checkbox] {
          opacity: 0;             /* checkboxes invisible and use no space */
         }                        /* display: none; is better but fails in ie8 */

        li .menu_label {
          cursor: pointer;        /* cursor changes when you mouse over this class */
     }                         /* could add the many user-select: none; commands here */

      li .menu_label + input[type=checkbox] + ol > li
         {
            display: none;         /* prevents sublists below unchecked labels from displaying */
         }

  li .menu_label + input[type=checkbox]:checked + ol > li
     {
       display: block;         /* display submenu on click */
     }



.selected {
     background-color:#efefef;
}
```

jquery

```
$('#move_left').click(function() {
$('.list1').append($('.list2 .selected').removeClass('selected'));
});

$('#move_right').click(function() {
$('.list2').append($('.list1 .selected').removeClass('selected'));
});

$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

HTML

```
    <body>
    <ol id="menutree">
<li>

    <label class="menu_label" for="c1">Menu Gen14 Am0a1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" />                             <!-- input must follow label for safari -->
<ol>
    <li>
    <ul class="list1">
        <li class="page">Page Ap1a1</li>
        <li> Page Ap1a2</li>
    </ul>


</ol>
</ol>
</body>
 <input type='button' value='<<' id='move_left'/>
    <input type='button' value='>>' id='move_right'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid example that does not take children ordering under consideration, but logic that you presented should be preserved

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3j94o6yc/)

```
<div class="half">
    <ol id="one">
        <li id="alaska">
            Alaska
            <ul>
                <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox"> Children 1</li>
                <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox"> Children 2</li>
                <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox"> Children 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="washington">
            Washington
            <ul>
                <li data-id="washington"><input type="checkbox"> Children 1</li>
                <li data-id="washington"><input type="checkbox"> Children 2</li>
                <li data-id="washington"><input type="checkbox"> Children 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="texas">
            Texas
            <ul>
                <li data-id="texas"><input type="checkbox"> Children 1</li>
                <li data-id="texas"><input type="checkbox"> Children 2</li>
                <li data-id="texas"><input type="checkbox"> Children 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <button type="button" class="include">Include</button>
</div>
<div class="half">
    <ol id="two"></ol>
    <button type="button" class="exclude">Exclude</button>
</div>

$(function(){
    $('.include').click(function(e){
        var $checks = $("input:checked");
        $.each($checks, function(k,v){
            var tempid = $(this).parent().data('id');
            if( !$('#two').find('[data-id="'+tempid+'"]').length ){
                var element = $(this).parent().detach();
                $('#two').append(element);
            }
        });
    });

    $('.exclude').click(function(e){
        var $checks = $("input:checked");
        $.each($checks, function(k,v){
            var tempid = $(this).parent().data('id');
            var element = $(this).parent().detach();
            $('#one').find('#'+tempid+' ul').append(element);
        });        
    });
});
```